# Dependencies in a clojurescript with leiningen

Tags: clojure, leiningen, clojurescript

I am seriously pulling my hair right now!  I am a total noob at clojure: I can't seem to be able to get a simple clojurescript compilation done without this error:

> ERROR: JSC_MISSING_PROVIDE_ERROR. required "clojure.core.async" namespace never provided at /home/jldupont/workspace/$someproject/target/cljsbuild-compiler-0/domain2/main.js line 4 : 0

I've got the following `project.clj` file:

```
(defproject $someproject "0.1"
  :description "some project..."
  :dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.5.1"]
                 [org.clojure/clojurescript "0.0-2030"]
                 [org.clojure/core.async "0.1.267.0-0d7780-alpha"]                 
                ]
  :plugins [[lein-cljsbuild "0.3.2"]]
  :cljsbuild {
              :builds [{:id "domain2"
                        :source-paths ["src/cljs/model2/domain"]
                        :compiler {:output-to      "src/assets/js/model2/domain/domain2.js"
                                   :optimizations :advanced
                                   :pretty-print   true}
                       }
                      ]
            }
)
```

Everytime I use `lein cljsbuild auto` I get the error quoted above.

Please help!

**Update**

I've looked in my `~/.m2` directory and the dependencies ( in this case core.async ) are present.

**Update 2**

It would appear that it is the Google Closure Compiler that spews out this error message. Not sure how to provide it a path to the dependencies...

Comment: I think your `:source-paths` is probably wrong. Try `:source-paths ["src/cljs"]` instead.

Comment: It finds my source files alright. That's not the problem.

Comment: Are you requiring the right namespace? It seems `cljs.core.async` is for ClojureScript and `clojure.core.async` for Clojure.

Comment: @xsc you nailed it!!! Right an answer and I'll accept it with pleasure.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As mentioned in my comment above: if you want to use `core.async` with ClojureScript you have to require the namespace `cljs.core.async` (instead of Clojure's `clojure.core.async`).